# Visual Studio 2015 Validation Warnings on every property "(CSS 3.0): [property] is not a known CSS property name."

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

I just updated to VS2015 and now on literally every single one of my stylesheets, SCSS and CSS alike, on every single rule, I get this validation warning.

```
"(CSS 3.0): [property] is not a known CSS property name."
```

Answer (score 0):

Bah! Disregard. Somehow I didn't notice I had opened something called "Blend" instead of VS.